# what to do with question which are solved in comments only

Tags: support, comments

I came across some questions which are simply answered in comments only and user itself says  "thanks it has done what is needed" but the question is still unanswered as no answer is accepted for it.

In flag as well there is no option to close such question.

Is there any way to force user to close his question if it is resolved by suggestion in comments only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there's no way to 'force' a user to take action, even if there is an answer.

Accepting an answer doesn't 'close' the question, it's just an indicator that the OP found that particular response to be helpful.

Please don't flag these questions just on the basis that there isn't an accepted answer, there's no need (they're fine as they are from that point of view).

What some people around the network recommend you do is leave a comment for the person who solved the issue, and ask them to put it in as an answer. If you don't hear anything back, just answer it yourself.

No need to feel bad about doing that, the goal of the site is to produce a good repository of information - for the most part it doesn't really matter how that information gets to be in the right place. If you feel bad about it you can always mark the answer as community wiki, so you don't receive reputation for it. Although that isn't necessarily the best use of that feature.

See also [Why do a lot of people seem to "answer" a question in the comments section?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/why-do-a-lot-of-people-seem-to-answer-a-question-in-the-comments-section)

Comment: Got some possible reasons of answering as comments from the link. The best one is being frightened of getting down-voted in case of incomplete answer. 
I think comments can also be accepted as answer, what you say?

Comment: It's been brought up before on the main SE meta site, it's been rejected every time as unnecessary. Comments are second-class citizens, and they can be removed at a moment's notice (doesn't always happen in practice). If something needs to stick around on a question, it needs to be in an answer

Comment: There is an exception your answer don't cover: If question was solved by cache clear, typo correction etc, it should be closed. Hints like that are usually in comments, as far as I notice.

Comment: Oh, and marking answer as CW makes it easier for the original commenter to edit it later, if he is low-rep. I don't quite believe it really happens that often, but it can. So marking it CW serves some additional purpose.